# Вопросы новичка по базовым частностям из учебников

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, тематика, правила

Допускаются ли вопросы новичка по маленьким базовым частностям языков, которые, скорее всего, есть в учебниках, но сложно находятся там?

Просто мне так проще изучать язык, но думаю, что это может быть вредным.

Answer (score 21):

Думаю, ничего страшного в этом нету. Таких вопросов на самом деле много ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/472992/10105)), и они полезны всем, не только вам.

Есть грань между «объясните, как `delete[]` знает сколько элементов массива удалять» и «вот код на паскале, переведите мне его на C++, не используя STL». Первый вопрос интересен и полезен, наталкивает на размышления и чему-то учит, второй неинтересен, бесполезен и лишь поощряет не учиться программированию.

Answer (score -7):

Часто можно видеть реально глупый/слишком простой вопрос (или несколько подряд) от пользователя с рейтингом 1. Значит, только что зарегистрировался и задал. Чаще всего эти вопросы по поводу домашних заданий (хотя и явно автор это не указывает). Почему бы не ввести правило, что задавать вопросы можно через n дней после регистрации? Зная жизнь студенческую, где все делается в последний вечер перед сдачей, такой подход, мне кажется, отсеет приличную часть таких вопросов при небольших n (сутки-двое). Регистрируясь, пользователь к тому же даст понять, что это не для одного вопроса (~Mail.Ответы), а для повышения своего уровня.

Comment: задать вопрос можно даже не регистрируясь

Comment: Бесполезно. Всегда можно найти миллион обходных путей