# Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, новые-участники, google-it

Недавно наткнулся на отличный комментарий (ещё эпохи ХэшКода). Он был к ответу, который состоял из предложения пойти поискать в поисковике, и сегодня этот ответ уже удален. Но сам комментарий настолько хорош, что я хочу сохранить его здесь, как образец здравого смысла.

> А если бы на поисковой запрос в Яндексе, вам бы выдавался ответ: "Хотелось бы уточнить, вы пробовали на ХэшКоде спросить?" Футболить - не благородное дело. ИМХО — Deonis Apr 4 '12 at 11:33

Да, бывает что вопросы задаются по совершенно базовым вещам. [Но и такие вопросы нужны.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1969/181472) Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики. Это они должны указывать на StackOverflow, а не наоборот.

Comment: А также, в частности, и отсутствием ответов вида «Погугли», «Читай Википедию» и «Юзай n» Stack Overflow качественно отличается от альтернативных сервисов. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну теперь не в комментариях отправляют, а сразу в ответах https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/813597/186083 `По запросу "slider carousel vue.js", пятая ссылка сверху в выдаче. ...`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

В простых вопросах нет ничего плохого. Можно даже говорить, что они крайне полезны (как и вопросы любой другой сложности).

#### Да вы даже не пытались разобраться! Пришли тут и задаете вопросы! Не хорошо!

[Как уже говорилось](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/681/6), простой вопрос - это не признак лености. Простой вопрос - это признак новичка. Процитирую.

> Для опытного специалиста характерны два важных качества:
>
> - широкое знание предметной области;
> - хорошая осведомленность о качественных источниках пополнения знаний.
>
> Поэтому при возникновении какой-либо задачи опытный специалист
>   (например, системный администратор):
>
> - в точности вспоминает, какую команду и как надо выполнить, поскольку он уже неоднократно ее исполнял;
> - в общих чертах вспоминает, какие команды могут подойти, и обращается к руководству пользователя, чтобы прояснить детали;
> - заходит на любимый сетевой ресурс, где можно найти подходящие руководства;
> - обращается к поиску, чтобы найти необходимый сетевой ресурс.
>
> Новичок же еще не знает ни предметной области, ни источников
>   информации. В дополнение, сам поиск информации является навыком,
>   который вырабатывается со временем. Также интересно то, что задать
>   вопрос намного сложнее, чем искать ответ через поисковик! Так для того
>   чтобы задать вопрос на Stack Overflow на русском, нужно:
>
> - зарегистрироваться;
> - осмыслить проблему;
> - сформулировать ее в терминах предметной области;
> - записать вопрос.
>
> Для того чтобы найти ответ в поисковой системе, нужно:
>
> - отправить запрос по ключевым словам;
> - просмотреть выдачу поисковой машины.
>
> Если человек разбирается в предметной области, то найти ответ через поиск гораздо быстрее и
>   проще, чем спросить на форуме и ждать ответа. Ежели человек только
>   начал разбираться в предметной области, то все наоборот. В таком
>   случае начинающий специалист просто не знает, что и как искать.

К слову, на вопрос «почему вы не задаете вопросы на Stack Overflow», самый популярный ответ – «потому что мне проще найти ответ в поисковике, чем задать вопрос на сайте».

#### Сайт знатоков

Stack Overflow – это сайт, от части, для знатоков (к слову, управлением содержимым сайта и сообществом занимаются именно знатоки, а не новички), которые хотят каталогизировать свои знания для себя и всего сообщества. Но невозможно просто взять и записать всю информацию, которая храниться в голове. Нам, знатокам, необходим «ключ», по которому её можно найти. Этим самым «ключом к знаниям» является вопрос. Если у нас не будет вопросов, знатокам будет крайне сложно делиться своими знаниями и опытом.

#### Простые вопросы – удел Stack Overflow на русском. Наши коллеги на Stack Overflow на английском точно профессионалы, не то что эти парни из «Рунета».

В корне не верно. Конечно на нем есть простые вопросы. Очень много простых вопросов. Попробуйте посмотреть на поисковую выдачу Google по запросу «jquery clone element». Для меня Stack Overflow выше в выдаче, чем официальная документация по функции *clone*. Более того, пожалуйста, обратите внимание на [1000 самых «востребованных сообществом» вопросов на Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits). Отличаются ли они повышенной сложностью? Нисколько.

#### Почему отвечать на «простые» вопросы на порядок *полезнее*, чем отсылать к поиску?

Потому что вопросы порождают ответы, а ответы – это новые знания, незаменимый опыт реальных разработчиков, который не найти ни в одном другом месте в Интернете. Пожалуйста, помните, отвечая пусть даже на простой вопрос, мы отвечаем не для того, кто его задал, а для сотен и тысяч наших коллег, которые в будущем столкнутся с аналогичной проблемой!

Нет повода для стеснений для публикации ответа на простой вопрос. Если  программист данного уровня задает данный вопрос, скорее всего, даже если вы более или менее быстро можете найти решение, он не смог самостоятельно найти ответ. Это означает, что ответ «из поисковой выдачи» либо непонятен, либо он размещен на «свалке информации», в которой может разобраться только специалист более высокого класса, то есть для автора вопроса ответ попросту не существует. Опубликуйте его! Именно так, уже на протяжении более чем семи лет, поступают наши англоязычные коллеги!

Только вместе, всем сообществом, мы сможем создать свободную базу прикладных решений на русском языке. Чтобы наша база знаний была полной, вопросы по основам программирования обязаны быть её частью!

Comment: Величайшие хиты, ха ) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits

Comment: Отличный ответ, а главное от админа. То, на что я уже давно не надеялся. Nicolas, неужели концепция изменилась? -)

Comment: @avp Она всегда была именно такой, как мне казалось.

Comment: А мне уже давно казалось, что она стала такой -- *главное, накапливать ЗНАНИЯ*, как следствие многие стали считать простые вопросы от новичков просто мусором (и тут встает вопрос о дубликатах). Возможно Вам стоило бы донести эту свою мысль (о важности простых вопросов) до активной части общества еще несколькими выступлениями в разных источниках (в т.ч. в чате, там обсуждения поактивней, чем тут).

Comment: @avp Очень интересное замечание. Мне казалось, что идея накопление знаний не конфликтует с простыми вопросами. Постараюсь быть внимательнее к этому аспекту.

Comment: здесь есть противоречие самому себе. Когда пишешь "Потому что вопросы порождают ответы, а ответы – это новые знания......который не найти ни в одном другом месте в Интернете." это довольно странно. Какие это новые знания, если введя в гугл приблизительный запрос ты получишь десяток ответов на даную тему? Как можно не посылать в гугл людей, которые ленятся искать перед тем как задавать вопрос?То есть люди даже не пробовали -и по формулировке видно. Кроме того, не посылая в гугл ты просто приучаешь людей вместо искания в будущем задавать вопросы сдесь. Что еще и сопутствует появлению дубликатов!

Comment: @Andrew Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чего вы взяли, что автор вопроса не пробывал искать? [Задать вопрос намного сложнее, чем выполнить поиск!](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/681/6). Идея Stack Overflow не в том, чтобы помочь конкретному человеку в конкретный момент времени, а собрать базу знаний. В этом контексте, совершенно не важно, как автор вопроса пришел к тому, чтобы его опубликовать. Ваш ответ – это лично ваш уникальный опыт, которого больше нигде нет (ни в документации, ни в примерах использования библиотек).

Comment: Дубли должны закрываться, чтобы сообщество могло собрать как можно больше информации по каждой проблеме в одном месте, не повторяясь многократно, что даст возможность непрерывно поддерживать релевантность представленной информации.

Comment: Я дал ответ почему я так думаю с примерами в новом ответе в даной теме.

Answer (score 6):

Приведенный комментарий вовсе не образец здравого смысла, это скорее прием речевой манипуляции *"вам ведь не понравится если..."*

Идея проекта SO замечательная - помогать друг другу. Но она переродилась в ленту блиц-вопросов и блиц-ответов. Море вопросов от "новичков", которые на сайте появляются чтобы задать свой единственный вопрос. Не потому что они не смогли разобраться, а потому что **даже и не попытались разобраться**. К сожалению, сообщество провоцирует подход "столкнулся с проблемой - зашёл на SO - нашел решение - заюзал". О том, чтобы при этом что-то отложилось в голове вообще речи не идет.

Здесь же, чем подход с закрытием вопросов, если такой вопрос уже был задан ранее, принципиально лучше *предложения загуглить*? С точки зрения задавшего вопрос новичка, это ведь одно и то же.

Comment: Велика вероятность, что причиной повторяющихся вопросов является не очень качетсвенный поиск

Comment: _Здесь же, чем подход с закрытием вопросов, если такой вопрос уже был задан ранее, принципиально лучше предложения загуглить?_ - при закрытии дубликатом для пользователя дается конкретная ссылка с ответами, со стороны поисковиков становится проще найти исходный вопрос

Comment: Кол-во SO посетителей с поисковиков на порядок больше всех остальных (google является основным UI для SO). Это значит, что по словам основателя SO: ["the only bad simple question is a duplicate simple question"](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685/23044). *"Принципиально лучше"* потому что нет ни одного ресурса по программированию, который даже близко бы подходил к высокому значению *сигнал/шум* при столь широком охвате тем (назовите альтернативы, если знаете). [Какими должны быть критерии оценки качества базы знаний?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Оставлю мнение от новичка.
Я задал тривиальный вопрос по java, точно такие же вопросы задавили до меня раза четыре, я их внимательно прочитал, причем не только на SO, но и на других сайтах.

Ни одна из рекомендаций у меня не сработала, поэтому я написал вопрос.
Вопрос сразу же был помечен как дубликат, что соответственно лишило меня возможности получить ответ от того, кто его пожелал бы дать.

В целом я пытался найти ответ целый день, но не смог.
Нашел чат в telegramm, задал вопрос и человек мне сразу подсказал.

Как оказалось причина была совершенно банальная - надо было при запуске из консоли заключить пути в кавычки!!

На эту фигню (которая нигде поиском не нашлась) я убил целый день.

Если не хотите отвечать - просто пройдите мимо.

В результате я написал ответ в комментарии - но при этом его никто не увидит потому что вопрос помечен как дубликат.

Пример:
[Error: Could not find or load main class2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/860064/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class2?noredirect=1#comment1387479_860064)

Comment: То есть у вас сработало не то решение, которое описано в «оригинале дубликата»? Если так, скажите, я отменю.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Там уже 4 голоса за переоткрытие, а вопрос - да, был закрыт с молота, без особого разбирательства.

Comment: @AK атата. Добил пятый голос )

Comment: Добавлю, что вам следовало бы с самого начала написать в чем отличие вашего случая от задававшихся много раз дубликатов. Возможно, тогда бы его и не закрывал никто.

Comment: Собственно предыдущие вопросы касались простейшего случая "Hello world", потому и не сработали. Поскольку вопрос в моем случае решен - то я написал предыдущий пост с целью проиллюстрировать позицию со стороны вопрошающего. Кстати второй момент - когда с кондачка на вопрос вешается дубликат - то отсутствует система обратной связи с кем либо кому можно пожаловаться на дубликат - и это тоже проблема. P.S. Кстати в само вопросе я прямо написал что искал ответы и они не помогли.

Comment: @ГайратВласов ну почему же не помогли-то? Дубликат-то снят...

Comment: «искал ответы и они не помогли» — в подобных случаях нужно пояснять, *почему* не помогли — тогда дубликатом закрывать не станут

Answer (score -1):

Поддерживаю ответ от **Denis Khvorostin**

> Приведенный комментарий вовсе не образец здравого смысла, это скорее
>   прием речевой манипуляции "вам ведь не понравится если..."

Но несколько дополню его. А так же прокритикую принятый основной ответ.

1. Есть в психологии человека такая вещь, как любовь к вниманию к себе и своим вопросам. В профессиональных кругах от этого уже избавились. Когда ты не профи -- ты чувствуешь такую потребность.
   И тебе приятно, когда тебе отвечают лично на заданный тобою вопрос. Ведь твоя проблема тебе кажется таааакой уникальной.
2. Также это освобождает от прочитывания "лишней информации". Не нужно выбирать "мусор" от ответа. Не нужно просматривать несколько страниц. Тебе на блюдечке все поднесут.

**Если людям не указывать на этот недостаток, ону будут продолжать плодить вопросы даже не пытаясь разбираться.** Как и написал Denis Khvorostin

Более того, я скажу что я сам таким страдал. И, даже, в свое время был за это забанен(и через время разбанен) в англоязычном стек оверфлоу. **И это правильно.**

> Велика вероятность, что причиной повторяющихся вопросов является не очень качественный поиск

**Cerbo**, **Причиной повторяющихся вопросов почти всегда яляется одна попытка поиска, вместо нескольких с вариантами других ключевых слов. В самом лучшем варианте. В худшем -- ни одной.** Если человек ленивый -- он не сделает и одного запроса, а пойдет и спросит на каком-либо сервисе.

Прекрасным подтверждением этого тезиса является сервис thequestion.ru, где количество дублирующихся вопросов исчисляется сотнями. Без преувеличения! Например, "как стать программистом гуманитарию?" один из таких вопросов. Люди тупо ленятся писать в гугл по названным выше причинам. Идете туда, вводите в поиск слово "программистом" и смотрите :) А если посмотреть запрос в гугле "как стать программистом" -- так вообще стооооолько ответов будет. Но людям же влом гуглить. А для чего?

**Не нужно в людях поощрять поведение "задай вопрос вместо гугления".** Если человеку что-то реально надо -- он будет искать это до посинения. Даже, если он задал вопрос на SO, он будет искать параллельно.

**Вот обьясните мне, как не посылать в гугл человека который вопрошает ответить "как написать класс карты на python" если эта же надпись("класс карты на python") даст ответ просто введя в гугл? Это не придуманный пример, это реальный вопрос на который я отвечал и посылал человека в гугл в конце своего ответа.**

---

Теперь перейдем к критике самого заплюсованого ответа:

> простой вопрос - это не признак лености. Простой вопрос - это признак
>   новичка. Процитирую.

Неееет. Простой вопрос с признаком лености вполне легко отличить от простого вопроса новичка, который гуглил!
Я покажу 2 примера. Уверен, ты сам догадаешься кто есть где:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630600/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-card-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%bf/630609#630609

и

[Для чего нужны get и set?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/56128/%d0%94%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-get-%d0%b8-set?s=2|1.4023)

В первом случае человек и не пытался. Это явно видно по вопросу. И абсолютно логично было бы просто послать его в гугл. Что я после ответа(!) и сделал(!).

Во втором случае -- человек пытается что-то понять. И это видно по самому вопросу!

> Потому что вопросы порождают ответы, а ответы – это новые знания,
>   незаменимый опыт реальных разработчиков, который не найти ни в одном
>   другом месте в Интернете. Пожалуйста, помните, отвечая пусть даже на
>   простой вопрос, мы отвечаем не для того, кто его задал, а для сотен и
>   тысяч наших коллег, которые в будущем столкнутся с аналогичной
>   проблемой!

Здесь есть противоречие самому себе. Это довольно странно. Какие это новые знания, если введя в гугл приблизительный запрос ты получишь десяток ответов на данную тему? Где же этот незаменимый опыт? Почему он незаменимый если его замену так легко найти за 2-3 минуты?

Чем поможет сообществу лишний вопрос и ответ на него, если в гугле и так первые 10 ссылок отвечают на него? Добавится еще 100тая? так человек и так не гуглит! **Будь там хоть 1000 ссылок, он их не увидит. Потому что, даже, не пробует набирать текст в гугле.**

Кроме того, не посылая в гугл ты просто приучаешь людей вместо искания в будущем задавать вопросы здесь. То есть, в том числе, поощряешь создание дубликатов!

> В дополнение, сам поиск информации является навыком, который вырабатывается со временем. 
>   C этим тезисом я согласен. На большинство вопросов сложно гуглить. Но те, с которыми в основном в гугл и посылают -- это не такие вопросы.

Какие именно навыки использования поисковой системы нужно иметь что бы нагуглить ответ для вопроса по созданию класа карты на питоне? "клас Карта Python" и "class card python" это сложно? Люди точно так же гуглят "зимние шины москва" а здесь им нужны навыки? Почему? Чем эти примеры поисковых запросов сложнее?

**Я ЗА посылание в гугл. Но лишь в случаях, когда явно видно, что человек даже не пытался разобраться в проблеме. И против посылания в гугл в простых вопросах, где реально видно, что человек пытается разобраться.**

Первые от вторых отличаются кардинально.

Я предлагаю поощрять посылание в гугл. Но с условием, что ответ так же будет даваться человеку, а не просто посыл в гугл. Людей нужно приучать сначала гуглить, а потом уже задавать вопросы.

---

Выдержка из комментариев:

> @Andrew, замечание про гугление никак не относится к ответу, если его
>   убрать, смысл решения не изменится, при этом, автор вопроса
>   выставляется в свете не очень умного человека

@Grundy Автор вопроса и так выглядит не очень умным, если у людей возникает желание попросить его гуглить перед вопросом :) Независимо от того кто-то просил его гуглить или промолчал. Замечание про гугл, может, к ответу и не относится, но уменьшает возможность, что будет задан еще не один десяток вопросов этим же человеком, на которые ответ легко нагуглить.

Если вопросы/ответы легко нагуглить, значит, и ценность таких вопросов нулевая. Как для сообщества, так и для интернета в целом.

> > Людей нужно приучать сначала гуглить, а потом уже задавать вопросы.
>
> это не является плюсом для проекта. На Stack Overflow приходят для
>   получения ответа по программированию, а не чтобы их жизни учили. Для
>   этого есть другие места, школа или институт, например. (c) Nicolas Chabanovsky

SO должно делать из новичков -- специалистов по программированию. Гугление перед задаванием вопроса -- это часть становления специалистом.

**При чем такая важная часть, что без нее ты не специалист в любом случае.** Лично я не знаю ни одного специалиста, который бы не гуглил перед задаванием вопроса другим людям или в сообществе.

Comment: зачем посылать в гугл, если можно закрыть вопрос как дубликат? А если дубликата нет, то и смысла посылать нет, так как это из поиска должны приходить на SO, а не наоборот.

Comment: _То есть, в том числе, поощряешь создание дубликатов!_ - дубликаты - это хорошо, они позволяют находить конечный вопрос/ответ по разным запросам.

Comment: Grundy, я расписал зачем в своем ответе. Перечитай, пожалуста.:)

Comment: Не нашел там ответа на мой комментарий :-)

Comment: Вы приводите критику на основе «обще известных фактов», которые я нигде не встречал. Пожалуйста, приведите ссылку на них, буду крайне рад прочитать эти исследования. _Если людям не указывать на этот недостаток_ – SO – это сайт вопросов и ответов по программированию, а не сайт указания на недостатки. Все подобные комментарии – ненужный шум, от которого мы как раз и хотим избавиться в нашем сообществе. _ будут продолжать плодить вопросы даже не пытаясь разбиратся_ – заданный вопрос – это и есть попытка разобраться.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky  Последний абзац моего ответа перечитай, пожалуста.

Comment: @Grundy дубликаты это плохо. Это забирает время у специалистов, которые тратят на них время, вместо того что бы отвечать реально нуждающимся людям. Которые не ленятся гуглить перед задаванием вопроса.

Comment: Каким образом вы узнаете, что человек пытался, а что нет? Вы не можете поставить себя на место задающего вопрос, у вас совершенно другой уровень знаний и понимания тематики. То, что для вас может быть очевидно, кристально понятно и являться ответом, для другого даже не вызовет ассоциацию с исходной темой.

Comment: Я выше навел пример с 2мя вполне конкретными темами SO. Чем этот пример не показательный?

Comment: @Andrew, как дубликаты забирают время у специалистов?

Comment: 1. Люди заходят посмотреть. 2.Отвечают. 3. Отмечают как дубликат. 4. Время на модерацию. Это все требует времени.

Comment: _Я предлогаю поощрять посылание в гугл_ – такого никогда не было и не будет. Сообщество приняло решени, что за подобные комментарии следует отстранять участников от сайта, сколько полезными не были бы их ответы, так как «посылая» в комментариях такой участник приносит намного больше вреда сообществу, чем пользы своими ответами, так как разобщает коллег и приносит вредоносный шум, злость и ругань.

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на вопрос http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535/, и статью из справочного центра: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @Andrew, любое действие требует времени, никто не заставляет его тратить

Comment: Чем ответ + замечание(совет?) что нужно гуглить (как я посоветовал выше) "приносит вредоносный шум, злость и ругань." можно узнать? Конечно же без агресии.

Comment: @Andrew, замечание про гугление никак не относится к ответу, если его убрать, смысл решения не изменится, при этом, автор вопроса выставляется в свете не очень умного человека

Comment: SO – не сайт для личной критик, это сайт ответов на вопросы по программированию. Все что выходит за рамки вопросов и ответов по программировани является вредоносным шумом.  До SO существовала множество форумов, одной из проблем которых был вредоносный шум, то есть когда автор задавая вопрос узнавал все политические шутки по теме, тренды моды, курсы валют, и еще в добавок много нового о себе, но крайне редко получал ответ.

Comment: @Grundy Автор вопроса и так выглядит не очень умным, если у людей возникает желание попросить его гуглить перед вопросом :) Независимо от того кто-то просил его гуглить или промолчал. Замечание про гугл, может, к ответу и не относится, но уменьшает возможность что будет задан еще один вопрос на который ответ легко нагуглить.

Comment: На Stack Overflow нет место чему–либо отличному от вопросов и ответов на них. Примерно также, как в Википедии.

Comment: @Andrew Унижая достоинства людей едкими комментариями мы, конечно же, снизим количество публикуемых вопросов (собственно, как и желание работать в индустрии с такими «коллегами»). Но (!) у нас нет такой задачи, и никогда не будет.

Comment: _Замечание про гугл, может, к ответу и не относится, но уменьшает возможность что будет задан еще один вопрос_. Вот такое должно было быть предложение :-) будет ли легко или сложно нагуглить ответ неизвестно, так как и вопроса просто не будет

Comment: Я перед тем как советовать искать в гугле проверяю на сколько информация легко ищется. По словам использованным в самой теме автором вопроса. Так что это вполне известно и "измеряемо" :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky чем конкретно просьба гуглить так унижает? Я же не посылаю в _______ или на _________. Я прошу просто гуглить перед задаванием вопроса. Эта просьба не является унижением в моих глазах. **Тем более, если эта просьба дана после ответа на вопрос топик стартера.**

Comment: @Grundy Нет, продолжение должно быть немного не такое. А следующее: Замечание про гугл, может, к ответу и не относится, но уменьшает возможность что будет задан еще один вопрос **на какой и так есть куча ответов, что позитивно скажется на качестве среднего вопроса SO.**

Comment: @Andrew Никто не хочет чувствовать себя глупым, не новичок, не профессионал. Публикуя подобный комментарий, как мне кажется, его автор пытается показать, насколько глуп автор вопроса, что даже не смог найти и понять решения. Подобное, как минимум, обидно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Вполне нормально что-то не знать. Вполне нормально что я не знаю чего-то. Что ты не знаешь чего-то с той сферы в которой знаюсь я иль кто другой. Но! Это неправильно занимать время других людей не попытавшись найти ответа самому. И такое поведение не должно поощрятся. Ни по отношению к тебе, ни по отношению к другим, ни по отношению ко мне. Сначала сам ищешь - потом уже спрашиваешь, если не удалось найти.

Comment: @Andrew, не не не, именно, просто может быть не задан вопрос. Вообще спор немного странный. Ответы должны находиться на SO. Следовательно есть два пути: если ответ уже на SO - надо закрыть как дубликат, если ответа на SO нет - нужно его написать. Здесь нет места прослойке в виде гугла, все предельно просто.

Comment: Поясню на личном примере. За время работы программистом, я участвовал в разработке нескольких ОС для встроенных систем, причем далеко не самых тривиальных их частей, но во время работы над проектами выходного дня у меня появляются [достаточно «простые» вопросы по JavaScript](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/), а иногда [даже очень простые](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614315/), поисковой запрос для поиска ответа на которые для меня не очевиден. Ответ в комментарии «это тривиально» или насмешка не добавляет их авторам «крутости», в глазах задавшего вопрос.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я могу дать гарантию того, что твой вопрос, каким бы он тривиальным не был, был задан разумно и по нему можно увидеть что ты искал. Как я скинул 2 примера выше -- одна категория людей вполне отличается от второй по стилистике задавания вопроса. :) А на вопрос человеку, который искал и не нашел приятно давать ответ. Upd: да, я просмотрел эти темы и скажу что по ним видно что ты пытался что-либо найти даже не особо вчитываясь в текст. :) Как по некоторым вопросам сразу видно что человек и не пытался найти.

Comment: Вся соль в том, что не существует (как минимум, я не знаю про такие) мат. средств, которые бы с заданной вероятностью сказали, кто искал много, чтобы задать вопрос, а кто искал мало для этого. Если средств нет, то вопросы от любого участника должны рассматриваться с одинаковым уважением как к проблеме, так и к личности автора. Иначе это уже клуб по интересам, а не база знаний сообщества.

Comment: При этом, конечно же, никто не отменяет требований к качеству вопросов.

Comment: Может, математических средств и нет, но есть опытные средства :) Возможно мне видно, потому что я обучал нескольких людей и видел как они гуглят и исправлял их. А так же видел когда они не пытались гуглить и задавали вопросы. Для меня это довольно увидеть с достаточно высокой точностью. И потому я могу быть не обьективным в этом вопросе(всем ли это видно?). Но с другой стороны, как я выше сказал -- не вижу ничего кардинально плохого в просьбе/рекомендации гуглить после ответа. Вижу значительно больше плюсов в этом.

Comment: Либо всем можно что–то, либо никому. Обычно, по другому не работает. У подобных «просьб» гораздо больше минусов. Все эти минусы перечислены не раз здесь, на Мете. Плюсов, к сожалению, я ни разу не видел.

Comment: Я перечислял выше :) Самый актуальный ответ про плюсы -- мой последний блок ответа под которым мы коментируем -- "выдержка из коментариев".

Comment: _Людей нужно приучать сначала гуглить, а потом уже задавать вопросы._ – это не является плюсом для проекта. На Stack Overflow приходят для получения ответа по программированию, а не чтобы их жизни учили. Для этого есть другие места, школа или институт, например.

Comment: То есть сообществом и тобой лично будет поощрятся, если я начну сюда писать вопросы, вместо гугления? Ты это мне хочешь сказать? :) А если серьезно: SO должно делать из новичков -- специалистов по программированию. Гугление перед задаванием вопроса -- это часть становления специалистом. Лично я не знаю ни одного специалиста, который бы не гуглил перед задаванием вопроса. А ты?

Comment: SO – это многократно используемая база знаний, которая создана дружным сообществом специалистов. На основном сайте нет места чему–либо кроме знаний – вопросов по программированию и ответов к ним. Все остальное выходит за рамки проекта. Если у вас есть умение (и желание) учить начинающих коллег основам постановки запросов к поисковику, пожалуйста, напишите про это вопрос с ответом на основном сайте или на Мете, или, в случае индивидуального подхода, используйте систему чатов.

Comment: Использование поиска – это навык, который приходит со временем. Опять же, мой личный опыт таков: мой друг, начавший работать на несколько лет позже меня, две недели не мог правильно собрать проект, он даже не мог понять, что не так. Не понимая в чем проблема невозможно сделать правильный запрос к поисковику! Именно по–этому я не смог найти ответ на свои вопросы по JavaScript – я просто не понимал, в чем ошибка. Проблема моего друга была настройках сборки проекта в VS. Простая опция компилятора, указание на которую у меня заняло 15 секунд и безуспешный поиск которой у друга занял 2 недели.

Comment: какие именно навыки использования поисковой системы нужно иметь что бы нагуглит ответ для вопроса по созданию класа карты на питоне? "клас Карта Python" и "class card python" это сложно? Люди точно так же гуглят "зимние шины москва" а здесь им нужны навыки? Почему? Чем эти примеры поисковых запросов сложнее? Заметь, я постоянно опираюсь на один и тот же вопрос. Что бы опиратся на конкретику хоть как-то, а не ударятся в пустую абстрактную полемику.

Comment: `Лично я не знаю ни одного специалиста, который бы не гуглил перед задаванием вопроса другим людям или в сообществе.` -- а я люблю спросить народ (если подозреваю, что кто-то быстро и толково ответит) перед тем, как стучать по клаве

Answer (score -1):

Простите что поднимаю очень старую тему, но иногда действительно не понимаю почему нельзя отправлять человека в поисковики. Например в этом конкретном случае объясните кто-нибудь пожалуйста почему в таких вопросах [нужен список всех рек, озёр, водоканалов России](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1409324/%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b7%d1%91%d1%80-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%a0%d0%be%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8) (просьбах) я не имею права отправить человека в поисковики? Тут же явно не работает принцип "Человек должен из поисковика попадать на сайт SO, а не наоброт". Мало этого, так и вопрос не относится к программированию.

Очень прошу без негатива. Это не возмущение, а действительно хочу знать причину, чтобы не совершать ошибки в подобных случаях

Comment: когда то давно я не мог понять, почему человек не может найти в гугле ответ на простой вопрос, который у меня был на первой странице. Я специально посмотрел на его скриншот поиска - там было совершенно другое. Сам вопрос был по делфи, но оказывается, что на тему делфи оказывается ещё есть машинные масла и контент для взрослых. И если до этого интересовался мотоциклами и ночной жизнью, то гугл никогда не расскажет как в делфи кнопку сделать.

Comment: @KoVadim Мне уже делали замечание по поводу оправки поисковики, но там был случай очень простого вопроса, с тех пор я не отправляю человека в гугл. В вопросе, что я указал в вопросе, нельзя помочь никак, кроме как сидеть самому искать весь список требований и отдать список ссылок. Ответ не включает в себя какие-либо знания. Не дашь ссылку на доки, не приведёшь пример и то я дал совет искать так же и на английском и ссылку из википедии для сравнения, что на английском больше информации. Или я неправильно понимаю и даже в таких случаях мы по хорошему должны помогать - предоставить список ссылок?

Comment: тут спорный вопрос. я обычно в таких случаях просто комментарием оставляю. И тут даже у особых модераторов нет чем возразить.

Comment: скорей проблема будет в том, что ссылки имеют способность устаревать, если просто ссылить человека по ним. В ответ - это точно не годится, а коммент не запретят. Тут согласен. На счет отправить в поисковик -> иногда лучше пройти мимо, чем указывать на несостоятельность вопрошающего погуглить. Вопрос закроют, если он не выдерживает никакой критики и ТСу придется искать альтернативные пути поиска информации, а там глядишь и поисковик ему не враг. И самолюбие ТСа не задето)

Comment: @Dmitry Я как раз как комментарий отписался, но мне его удалили с указанием, цицирую сообщение от модераторов "В поисковики никогда нельзя отправлять". И этот "никогда" немного смутил меня, ибо  как минимум бывают случаи, когда нужно показать несколько примеров (сылку на такой вопрос дам ниже) и я так делал и указывал по каким ключевым словам можно искать и меня тогда никто не покарал за такое и я подумал что - это разумный момент, когда можно отправить на поиски с советом. Но в целом понял, просто не отвечать на такие вопросы - будет лучше для всех :)

Comment: @Dmitry А вот и сам вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1406027/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-js-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0#comment2499710_1406027

Comment: @EzioMercer как и за что вас покарает? Вы же не ответ пишите, а комментарий. И вы ссылкой не в поисковик, а на пример реализации отправили. Если бы вы еще и ответ написали, с названием библиотеки/фреймворка и ссылку на проект/документацию оставили, то вообще бы все шикарно было. А если бы еще и пример скрафтили - цены бы вам не было). Обратите внимание на ответы [Alexandr_TT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/28748/alexandr-tt) - про в svg и частенько дает ссылки на проекты в области фронта. Ответы шикарные

Comment: @Dmitry Я, может не так выразился, простите, но я имею ввиду, что тот случай я голову свёл к случаю вопроса, который указан в вопросе. И потому почти так же ответил только в комментариях, дал совет как лучше поискать и дал показательный пример, что на других языках может быть больше информации. Но в этот раз мне сделали предупреждение. И я не понял, почему это 2 совершенно разных случая, а не одинаковых?

Comment: @EzioMercer разное время/люди/вопросы/обстоятельства и еще много разных факторов, на которые вы не повлияете. Проще относитесь и пишите ответы=)

Comment: @Dmitry Понял, спасибо!) Просто не хотелось бы получить бан из-за таких вещей, потому решил спросить, т.к. это уже второе предупреждение на эту тему и немного запаниковал)