# Допустимость отправки участников в ChatGPT

Tags: обсуждение, faq, вопросы, новые-участники, генеративный-ии

В последнее время иногда вижу под вопросами комментарии вида "попробуйте попросить у ChatGPT, обычно подобные вопросы туда адресуются". Насколько я помню, аналогичная отправка участников в Google у нас не приветствуется, и по идее в ChatGPT отправлять участников тоже не нужно.

Хотелось бы услышать мнение других участников и модераторов по этому вопросу - насколько это допустимо, и стоит ли ставить тревогу на такие комментарии?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Всё то же самое, что и с "иди гугли".

Мы [не отправляем участников в поисковые системы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2166/373567), а ChatGPT это разновидность поисковой системы, в данном контексте его можно и нужно так воспринимать.

За отправку участника в ChatGPT в комментариях, модераторами будут приниматься такие же меры, как при отправке в Гугл, Яндекс или другие поисковики. Используйте сигнал тревоги, чтобы привлечь внимание модератора к таким комментариям.